# Determine if an SObject has an error

Tags: trigger, validation-rule, sobject, error-messages, adderror

Is there a way to calculate if an SObject in a trigger context has had an error added to it (either with `addError` or through a validation rule)?

I have some trigger processes I don't want to run if we don't end up inserting/updating this sobject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Winter '21, there is a method called `hasErrors()` on SObjects ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_hasErrors)).  The way to solve this problem now is to call:

```
Account acct = new Account();
// doSomething to acct;
if (!acct.hasErrors()) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a direct method for determining if an sObject has errors on it. There might be a method to tell, but I would rely on the triggers order of operations here. Any DML operations will fail if there's an added error, so by running those processes in an `after` trigger context will ensure that the record survived the initial process without getting an error added.

---

Looks like `ApexPages.HasMessages()` will return true in a trigger context! Not only that, but the severity parameters will return accurate information. `ApexPages.GetMessages()` will even go as far as to return the actual messages added, despite there being no page associated with the trigger.

Execute Anon Snippet:

```
insert new Account(Name = 'Test');
```

Trigger (Set up to fail & print message info)

```
trigger TestTrigger on Account (before insert) {

    for (Account a:trigger.new) {
        a.Name.AddError('Forced Failure');
    }

    System.debug(ApexPages.hasMessages()); // true 
    System.debug(ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR)); // true 

    for (ApexPages.Message message:ApexPages.getMessages()) {
        System.debug(message.getComponentLabel()); // Account Name 
        System.debug(message.getDetail()); // Forced Failure 
        System.debug(message.getSeverity()); // Error 
        System.debug(message.getSummary()); // Forced Failure 
    }
}
```

All the methods of `ApexPages.Message` return useful information, but since the `Message` class was designed to work with standard visualforce pages, which have only a single record related to that page, they don't seem to store the id of the record with the message, which is a problem for determining which records have failed.

Theres a constructor to create a `Message` with an Id, but it looks like its meant for a visualforce element id, not a record id, and theres still no easy way to get that value..

Comment: Wow! What a discovery!  It doesn't address the problem since some records may pass and some may fail, but this is very useful information

Comment: At the very least, this lets you do `if (!ApexPages.HasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR)) { //.. }` to control entering expensive calls. .

Comment: Also note that there isn't a way to clear page messages once added, so once added, you're stuck with them for the rest of the transaction (again, tying in to how this is really meant for Visualforce).

Comment: You can kind of use messages to report errors with ids, by calling something like `ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(Severity, 'Error Info', 'Details', 'RecordId'));` instead of using `sObject.addError`, but since you can't do `sObject.Field.AddError(new ApexPages.Message)` its kind of pointless - you might as well write your own error handling framework instead of trying to force messages to work outside of their intended context. Even if there were ids available through messages, not all trigger records will have an id, so it only kind of helps.

Comment: Getting error: `ApexPages.hasMessages can only be called from a Visualforce page `

Comment: As of Winter '21 (v50.0) there is a new method on SObjects that do this (`hasErrors()`)